# ASP.NET MVC 3 Range Validator fails when page is loaded, but text validation works fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, range

When my page loads in "edit" mode, my text fields render correctly, but my numeric fields render with the error validation text visible, even though the value in the field is valid:

[image: numeric field loads with error text]

My problem is in a more complex project, but I was able to reproduce it in an out-of-the-box MVC 3 application in which I just added these bits.  Why does the numeric field display the error text but the text field is fine when the page loads?

What is going on here?

I have the following for my Model, Controller, and View:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcIssues.Models
{
    public enum Operations
    {
        View = 0,
        Edit = 1
    }

    public class ShowsModel
    {
        public Operations Operation { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Number")]
        [Required]
        [Range(typeof(int), "1", "999")]
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcIssues.Models;
using MvcIssues.Data;

namespace MvcIssues.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /Test/Shows
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        [ActionName("Shows")]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult SelectedShows()
        {
            ShowsData shows = MvcApplication.Shows;

            ShowsModel model = new ShowsModel();

            model.Operation = Operations.View;
            model.Name = shows.Name;
            model.Number = shows.Number;

            return View(model);
        }


        // POST: /Test/Shows
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [ActionName("Shows")]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult ShowsSubmit(ShowsModel data)
        {
            string name = data.Name;
            int number = data.Number;

            ShowsModel model = new ShowsModel();

            if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("btnEdit"))
            {
                ShowsData shows = MvcApplication.Shows;
                model.Name = shows.Name;
                model.Number = shows.Number;

                model.Operation = Operations.Edit;
            }
            else if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("btnCancel"))
            {
                ShowsData shows = MvcApplication.Shows;

                model.Name = shows.Name;
                model.Number = shows.Number;

                model.Operation = Operations.View;
            }
            else if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("btnSaveEdit"))
            {
                ShowsData shows = MvcApplication.Shows;

                shows.Name = name;
                shows.Number = number;

                model.Name = shows.Name;
                model.Number = shows.Number;

                model.Operation = Operations.View;
            }

            return View("Shows", model);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcIssues.Models.ShowsModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2>Test Page</h2>

<div>
    Show = @this.ViewData.Model.Name
    <br />
    Number = @this.ViewData.Model.Number.ToString()
</div>

<hr />

<div>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "oops!")

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>

            Name: @(this.ViewData.Model.Operation == MvcIssues.Models.Operations.View ?
                Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { disabled = "disabled", maxLength = "20" })
            :
                Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)

            <br />

            Number: @(this.ViewData.Model.Operation == MvcIssues.Models.Operations.View ?
                Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number, new { disabled = "disabled" })
            :
                Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Number)

        </div>

        <div>
            @switch (this.ViewData.Model.Operation)
            {
                case MvcIssues.Models.Operations.Edit:
                    <input type="submit" name="btnSaveEdit" value="Save" />
                    <input type="submit" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" />
                    break;
                case MvcIssues.Models.Operations.View:
                default:
                    <input type="submit" name="btnEdit" value="Edit" />
                    break;
            }
        </div>        
    }

</div>
```

If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note, that if, after the page is loaded, I enter a numeric value into the Number field, the error text goes away.  Enter an invalid number into the field and the error text reappears.  So that appears to be working fine.  It is just when the page loads after clicking the Edit button.

Comment: Not sure it'll fix it, but why not just use `[Range(1, 999)]` for your `RangeAttribute`?

Comment: That was what I had originally, but no luck.

Comment: I'm thinking that it may have something to do with the fact that I have the same view for both "View" and "Edit" modes.  Can't change that now, though, and since it is working for the text field, it seems like it should also work for the number field - something tricky with the Range attribute that I don't know about?

Comment: Okay, more info: perhaps it has more to do with the [Required] attribute.  When I add that to the Name field of my model, I get the same behavior for the text field as well.  If I remove [Required] from the Number field, I still have the problem - seems I read something somewhere that stated that [Range()] implies [Required].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, posted [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1823443.aspx/1?ASP%20NET%20MVC%203%20RequiredAttribute%20Validator%20fields%20display%20error%20text%20when%20page%20loads%20even%20theough%20there%20is%20valid%20data) to asp.net forum.  Probably a little bit more concisely worded version of the same question.

Solution was a bit of a hack but seems to be working well - created empty constructors for my problematic view model classes and inside the empty constructors I initialized the properties to valid values.  Did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too.  Here's what caused it, and how I fixed it:

The cause:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BidToolv2(BidToolv2ViewModel model)
{
    ...
```

The fix:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BidToolv2()
{
    BidToolv2ViewModel model = new BidToolv2ViewModel();
```

Essentially the problem was when the user first visited the page, the controller took an empty model and when the page loaded, it assumed it had already been passed the model (perhaps?).  Not totally sure on that, but to fix it I removed the model as a parameter and instead created a model in the controller action itself

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need Required to make sure something is entered.

You need Range to make sure when something is entered that the values meet your requirements

```
    Example:



    [Required(ErrorMessage="Weekly Rental value is required")]
    [Range(1, 9999, ErrorMessage = "Value must be between 1 - 9,999")]
    public string WeeklyRental { get; set; }
```